# Can you pass GETDATE() to a SQL Job that runs SSIS Packages (Set Values)

Tags: ssis, sql-agent-job

I haven't been able to find a straight forward answer to this.  What I'm trying to accomplish is to execute a SSIS package that requires variables to be set, so I need to pass these variables to SSIS through the SQL Job.  I know this is possible through the "Set Values" tab, but I need to pass the current date, so hard-coding a string will not work.

Is it possible to pass GETDATE() or other expressions to the Value field within Set Values?  In other words, does the "Value" field get evaluated at runtime?

If this is not possible, what would be a good solution to pass the current day from the SQL job to the corresponding parameter in the SSIS package?

Comment: Can the SSIS package not just work out the current date for itself?

Comment: Yes... that was a poor example.  More generally, can the "Set Values" evaluate statements passed in, or does it have to be hard coded strings/ints?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no. It is not possible assign a method such as GETDATE() to the value property of a datetime variable through the Set Values screen of the SQL Agent Job. The value fields there must be set to discrete values.

I can think of two ways around this.

The first - and easiest option - is editing the package.  Open the package with BIDS/SSDT, find that variable, and set that "Evaluate As Expression" property of that variable to True.  Then in the properties window of that Variable, click the Expression ellipsis... and set Expression equal to GETDATE().  Save package. When the package runs, that variable will evaluate to GETDATE().

The second method takes a bit more sweat, and has risks, but allows you to dynamically set SSIS package variables.  Instead of using SQL Server Job to call a package.  Scheduled job which calls an SP.  This SP will then execute the SSIS package using xp_cmdShell and the DTEXEC.exe command line tool. 
Here is an [example](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2135/run-ssis-using-xpcmdshell-in-a-sql-server-stored-procedure/).  The DTEXEC.EXE command line tool has a /SET argument that basically does the same thing as the Set Values dialog box.  But this way its dynamic. Inside the SP you can

```
 DECLARE @MyDate datetime 
 SET @MyDate = GETDATE()
```

You just need to get your @MyDate value over to the /SET argument of DTEXEC.
Also, instead of GETDATE() you could also have a parameter that lets you build this date variable on the command line from a combination of substrings of the %DATE% and %TIME% system environmental variables.

```
set MyDate=%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~7,2%-%DATE:~4,2% %TIME:~0,8%    
dtexec /FILE "\"D:\SSIS\Package1.dtsx\"" /SET "\"\Package.Variables[VarDateTime].Value\"";"\"%MyDate%\""
```

An example of that is over [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bfc458e9-6046-4d4a-a366-46eaffea58ee/how-to-set-system-date-to-a-variable-in-ssis-package-from-sql-job#4).

Obviously, option one is easier and less risky.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When a job kicks off an SSIS package, the parameters it passes have to be hard-coded in the job.

If you need to pass more context-sensitive values to the package, the best way I've found to do it is to populate a meta-data table in your database, and have the first step in the job be to select the latest row from that table and populate variables from it.